# Avoid adding unnecessay Windows %PATH% to Git Bash

Tags: path, mingw, git-bash, msys

Unlike [Windows & Git Bash: Bash PATH to read Windows %PATH% system variable](https://superuser.com/questions/607533/windows-git-bash-bash-path-to-read-windows-path-system-variable), I am trying to avoid Git Bash from adding many entries from windows %PATH%.

The reason is my Windows %PATH% has many software installation directories added by our system admin. I do not want to remove them from Windows %PATH%, or some preinstalled software may not function properly. Neither do I want them in Git Bash because I do not need those stuffs to use Git.

I also learned from web that there is usually a "MSYS2_PATH_TYPE" I can set in `msys2.ini`, however, this file is not found in Git Bash installation directory.
Interestingly, `/etc/profile` seems to check this variable then determine which paths to add.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  It should not matter what is contained in the PATH variable.  Have you asked your Administrator for assistance with your problem?  Any modifications to your system should be done by a local Administrator.

Comment: @Ramhound I do not need to modify my system. I just do not want the Windows %PATH% var in Git Bash's $PATH